# How can we calculate the size of JsonNode in bytes/Kb/mb in Java?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a requirement to calculate the size of a Json response in bytes in java. Is there a way to calculate this in bytes/kb/mb in java.

Also , In java , We use jackson library to create the JsonNode.

We tried to calculate the size using below. Not sure that is giving correct or exact size .

jsonResponse.toString().getBytes().length

We would need to compare the size of the json output taken through database and with the one formed in java code.  So in postgresql we have pg_column_size() to calcualte the size of the json response. But in java , Not sure we have any direct way to get the size of json ?

Comment: What is the "JSON response"? Is it a web request esponse? A file reader response? Database call? Something else? This needs some more details that tells us what your code is doing before folks can get you the right answer.

Comment: It is a json output from postgresql database through database call .

Comment: Don't just tell me, remember to [put those details in your post](/help/how-to-ask). Can you show the code you're using to get that JSON? Because JSON itself is just text, figuring out the size of the database response is probably just checking the string length.

Comment: It all depends on what you really mean by _"size of JSON"_. If you mean how many bytes to store this JSON as text, then your solution seems OK. Even though keep in mind that a HTTP response contains additional data and might be compressed.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is to render the JSON as a String, then get the length:

```
int calculateSize(JsonNode jsonNode) throws JsonProcessingException {
    var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    var string = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
    return string.length();
}
```

This operation can be time/memory consuming, since the full JSON content need to be rendered as a `String`.

A better approach is to use a recursive function to traverse the JSON node adding up the total size:

```
int calculateSize(JsonNode jsonNode) {
    if (jsonNode == null) {
        return 4; // null
    }
    if (jsonNode.isTextual()) {
        return 2 + jsonNode.asText().length(); // two quotes + string
    }
    if (jsonNode.isArray() || jsonNode.isObject()) {
        var size = new AtomicInteger(2); // square/curly brackets
        if (jsonNode.isObject()) {
            jsonNode.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(
                    field -> size.getAndAdd(3 + field.length())); // quoted key and colon
        }
        if (!jsonNode.isEmpty()) {
            size.getAndAdd(jsonNode.size() - 1); // commas
            jsonNode.elements().forEachRemaining(
                    element -> size.getAndAdd(calculate(element))); // recurs
        }
        return size.get();
    }
    return jsonNode.asText().length(); // boolean, number
}
```

This method will traverse the JSON content, but the memory consumption will be minimal.

> Note: some implementations can differ when rendering JSON, e.g., in Javascript, numbers with scientific notation can have different lengths than the equivalent in Java.